# wanting normal text in window title but not chinese letters

Tags: c++, winapi

```
HWND hwnd;
void makeWindow() {
        const char* onlyOneWindowClass = "general";
        HINSTANCE moduleHandle = GetModuleHandle(0);
        WNDCLASSEXA wc;
        wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXA);
        wc.style = 0;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc2;
        wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wc.hInstance = moduleHandle;
        wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
        wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        wc.lpszClassName = onlyOneWindowClass;
        wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        RegisterClassExA(&wc);
        hwnd = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, onlyOneWindowClass, "temp", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 240, 120, NULL, NULL, moduleHandle, NULL);
}
```

I call above procedure like below:

```
   makeWindow();
    //some code here
    SetWindowTextA(hwnd, "want not chinese");
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
```

Above is how I set window Text but I get only chinese letters. What is wrong?

Comment: why do you code this yourself. there is a doc online on how to create a window the correct way https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-a-window

Comment: Why do you use ANSI versions of the API? In 2020 one should ditch them in favor of Unicode ones, e.g. use `CreateWindowExW` instead of `CreateWindowExA`.

Comment: Set the character set for your program to Multi-Byte in the Project->Advanced properties. Or, just use embrace Unicode and be happy.

Comment: @RetiredNinja "*Set the character set for your program to Multi-Byte*" - that only affects TCHAR-based APIs, which the code shown is not using (unless they are being used in code we can't see, such as the message loop using `DispatchMessage()` instead of `DispatchMessageA()`, etc)

Comment: @RemyLebeau It changes the macros to use the A functions by default instead of the W functions so it's harder to have a mismatch. But yes, if you use `GetMessageA`, `DispatchMessageA`, and `DefWindowProcA` it also fixes the issue.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I'm aware of what the charset project setting does.  My point was, the code shown by the OP is using the `A` functions directly and thus would not be affected by any changes to the project setting. Only code outside of what was shown would be affected, if any.

Comment: @RemyLebeau IMO it's better to not have to try and figure out all the functions that have an A/W version if you're dead set on using the A versions everywhere. Until today I had no idea there even was a `DefWindowProcA`, so thanks for pointing me in the direction to learn something new that I hope I won't ever need to know again. :)

Comment: The bug is in your `WndProc2`. It's probably calling `DefWindowProcW` when it should be calling `DefWindowProcA`. Though, that's speculation, until we see a [mcve].